# membership calculation logic in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a set of members and their coverage start dates but no end dates. I need to write a query which will help me figure out how many unique members are part of the list in any given year. So basically, I need a count of unique members broken down by year when i only have the start date of their membership with me but no end dates. This will give me an idea as to how many dropped out in each year.

Input

```
Member  Start date  End date
------------------------------
A       1/1/2016    
B       1/2/2016    
C       1/3/2016    
D       1/2/2017    
E       1/3/2017    
F       1/5/2018
```

The expected result will be:

```
Year    Member Count    
---------------------
2016    3   
2017    2   
2018    1
```

If the member is included in the count for 2016, 2017 then it means that he has been with me for 2 years. I know the start date and I'll assign 12/31 of the year till when he was there as the end date, this gives me the time for which he was my customer. Hope this makes sense. The reason I need to figure out when the customer is dropping out is so that i know not just how many customers i have in any year but also how many dropped out in a certain year and the duration for which he was a customer. Hope this makes sense.

[input/output explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCuMy.png)

Hi All,

Please ignore the first part of the question, let me rephrase the problem.

In the above example, assuming I have the member id and the start date which indicates the date from which he is a customer. Is it possible to find the count of distinct members broken down by month and year who are eligible and to find count of distinct members broken down by month and year who have become eligible in that particular month?

ex, starting from jan 2011, if we had 10 customers, in feb, 5 new customer joined, 8 from the previous month are still my customers so the count of distinct customers in feb is 13 and overall new members in feb is 5

Comment: Maybe if you have a record of their last  payment in another table can be helpful, to solve this thing you will need to dig deeper in your database or even into papers (reports, bills, notes...) to fill in that data

Comment: Hi Daniel, we can work under the assumption that if we find a customer part of our list in 2016 and dont see that id in 2017 then he has dropped out. There is no need to delve into the other aspects. Appreciate your help

Comment: It seems that you're sample data doesn't represent your actual data at all. There are no member IDs that repeat. No member that appears in any year appears in any other year.

Comment: In your actual data, can a member have more than one start date? If so, can there be multiple start dates in the same year?

Comment: In this case, please share more representative sample data, your real expected result (Patrick's answer reaches the current one but you didn't accept the answer) and what have you tried so far. Here we are a lot of people willing to help, but we need something to start with, this is not enough

Comment: The image doesn't explain nothing at all, probably you wanted in that format, but doesn't make any sense with the given input, nor you or your new sample answer Eric's questions.... Flagging to close as unclear

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

From what I can infer by reading your question, having the end date doesn't really matter. Group by the year and count the distinct member IDs:

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(StartDate) 
    , COUNT(DISTINCT MemberID)
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY YEAR(StartDate)
ORDER BY YEAR(StartDate)
```

If you only want results where the members are missing and end date, add `WHERE EndDate IS NULL` before the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out Patrick. Actually, the requirement is that I get a bifurcation as to which members are carrying forward and which are dropping out. I need to understand which and how many members are carrying forward over the years so I come to know the length of time from the start date that the customer has been with me, hope this gives more context

Comment: How do you determine if a member is carrying forward or dropping out?

Comment: @priyesha if this answer does not respond the question, then the question is wrong, It returns exactly what you are asking for, please edit your question and add more detail

Comment: Plus one, it may not be what the OP needs, but it is what the OP asked for.